# Como compilar esse código em Assembly no Windows?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86

Estava vendo uma criação de uma janelinha básica em *Assembly* que exibe uma mensagem, já instalei o compilador *NASM* mas da erro para compilar.

```all
.386
.MODEL FLAT, STDCALL

INCLUDE windows.inc
INCLUDE kernel32.inc
INCLUDE user32.inc
INCLUDELIB kernel32.lib
INCLUDELIB user32.lib

.DATA
    WndClsName BYTE "AsmWnd", 0h;
    WndTitleName BYTE "Hello, World!", 0h;
    MsgBoxTxt BYTE "Programadores de verdade programam assim", 0h;
    CmdShow DWORD SW_SHOWDEFAULT;

.DATA?
    window WNDCLASSEX {};
    hInstance HINSTANCE ?;
    hWnd HWND ?;
    message MSG {};

.CODE
Entry:
    push 0h;
    call GetModuleHandle;
    mov hInstance, eax;

    mov window.cbSize, SIZEOF WNDCLASSEX;
    mov window.hbrBackground, COLOR_WINDOW;
    mov window.hIcon, 0h;
    mov window.hIconSm, 0h;
    mov window.cbClsExtra, 0h;
    push IDC_HAND;
    push 0h;
    call LoadCursor;
    mov window.hCursor, eax;
    push hInstance;
    pop window.hInstance;
    mov window.lpszMenuName, 0h;
    mov window.lpszClassName, OFFSET WndClsName;
    mov window.style, CS_VREDRAW or CS_HREDRAW;
    mov window.lpfnWndProc, OFFSET WndProc;

    push eax;
    lea eax, window;
    push eax;
    call RegisterClassEx;
    pop eax;

    push 0h;
    push hInstance;
    push 0h;
    push 0h;
    push 250d;
    push 250d;
    push 250d;
    push 250d;
    push WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;
    lea eax, WndTitleName;
    push eax;
    lea eax, WndClsName;
    push eax;
    push WS_EX_TOPMOST;
    call CreateWindowExA;
    mov hWnd, eax;
    cmp hWnd, 0h;
    jne _Ok;
    push 1h; 
    call ExitProcess;
    _Ok:
    push CmdShow;
    push hWnd;
    call ShowWindow;
    push hWnd;
    call UpdateWindow;

    _GetMessageLoop:
    push 0h;
    push 0h;
    push 0h;
    lea eax, message;
    push eax;
    call GetMessage;
    cmp eax, 0h;
    je _EndMessageLoop;
    lea eax, message;
    push eax;
    call TranslateMessage;
    lea eax, message;
    push eax;
    call DispatchMessage;
    jmp _GetMessageLoop;

    _EndMessageLoop:

    mov eax, message.wParam

WndProc proc hWindow:HWND, uMsg:UINT, wParam:DWORD, lParam:DWORD

    cmp uMsg, WM_DESTROY;
    je _WM_DESTROY;
    cmp uMsg, WM_LBUTTONDOWN;
    je _WM_LBUTTONDOWN;

    push lParam;
    push wParam;
    push uMsg;
    push hWindow;
    call DefWindowProc;
    jmp _EndWndProc;

    _WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    push MB_OK or MB_ICONINFORMATION;
    push OFFSET WndTitleName;
    push OFFSET MsgBoxTxt;
    push hWindow;
    call MessageBoxA;
    jmp _EndWndProc;

    _WM_DESTROY:
    push 0h;
    call PostQuitMessage;

    _EndWndProc:

    Ret
WndProc EndP

END Entry;
```

Comment: Parece ser a sintaxe do [MASM](http://www.masm32.com/). Poste as mensagens de erro.

Comment: E como compilar?

Comment: Se for mesmo MASM, com o compilador do MASM.

Comment: Assim é em Masm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para compilar esse código, você deve usar o compilador do [***MASM***](http://www.masm32.com/), não [***NASM***](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html), são [*montadores*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly#Montador) distintos.

Para que o seu código execute, faça as seguintes alterações:

1. Abaixo da diretiva `.model`, use a diretiva [`option casemap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zc781yh.aspx), `option casemap` pode ser `ALL`, `NONE` ou `NOTPUBLIC`, sendo está última a padrão. Usando `option casemap:none`, o *MASM* preserva a caixa dos identificadores. Usando `option casemap:all`, o *MASM* passa todos os identificadores para maiúsculo, por exemplo, tanto `msgboxtxt` quanto `MsgBoxTxt` são transformados em `MSGBOXTXT`). O objetivo é usar `NONE` para que a caixa dos identificadores sejam preservadas, então abaixo da diretiva `.model` faça:

   ```all
   .386
   .MODEL FLAT, STDCALL
   option casemap:none
   ```
2. Para evitar o erro *fatal error A1000: cannot open file*, coloque o caminho completo dos arquivos `.inc` e `.lib`. Troque:

   ```all
   INCLUDE windows.inc
   INCLUDE kernel32.inc
   INCLUDE user32.inc

   INCLUDELIB kernel32.lib
   INCLUDELIB user32.lib
   ```

   Por:

   ```all
   include \masm32\include\windows.inc
   include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
   include \masm32\include\user32.inc

   includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
   includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
   ```
3. Salve o arquivo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>*+*<kbd>S</kbd>, e no menu superior clique em *Project* ⇢ *Build All*, depois execute o programa clicando em *Run Program*.

   Resultado:

   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código pode ser reduzido usando o [`INVOKE`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/73407) para chamar uma função, ao invés de colocar os argumentos da função na pilha e chamar a função com `CALL`.

```apollo
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none

include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include \masm32\include\user32.inc

includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib

.DATA
    WndClsName BYTE "AsmWnd", 0h;
    WndTitleName BYTE "Hello, World!", 0h;
    MsgBoxTxt BYTE "Programadores de verdade programam assim", 0h;
    CmdShow DWORD SW_SHOWDEFAULT;

.DATA?
    window WNDCLASSEX {};
    hInstance HINSTANCE ?;
    hWnd HWND ?;
    message MSG {};

.CODE
Entry:
    invoke GetModuleHandle, 0h;
    mov hInstance, eax;
    mov window.cbSize, SIZEOF WNDCLASSEX;
    mov window.hbrBackground, COLOR_WINDOW;
    mov window.hIcon, 0h;
    mov window.hIconSm, 0h;
    mov window.cbClsExtra, 0h;
    invoke LoadCursor, 0h, IDC_HAND;

    mov window.hCursor, eax;
    push hInstance;
    pop window.hInstance;
    mov window.lpszMenuName, 0h;
    mov window.lpszClassName, offset WndClsName;
    mov window.style, CS_VREDRAW or CS_HREDRAW;
    mov window.lpfnWndProc, offset WndProc;

    invoke RegisterClassEx, offset window;
    invoke CreateWindowExA, WS_EX_TOPMOST, offset WndClsName, offset WndTitleName, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 250d, 250d, 250d, 250d, 0h, 0h, hInstance, 0h;
    mov hWnd, eax;
    cmp hWnd, 0h;
    jne _Ok;
    invoke ExitProcess, 1h;

    _Ok:
    invoke ShowWindow, hWnd, CmdShow;
    invoke UpdateWindow, hWnd;

    _GetMessageLoop:
    invoke GetMessage, offset message, 0h, 0h, 0h;
    cmp eax, 0h;
    je _EndMessageLoop;
    invoke TranslateMessage, offset message;
    invoke DispatchMessage, offset message;
    jmp _GetMessageLoop;

    _EndMessageLoop:
    mov eax, message.wParam

WndProc proc hWindow:HWND, uMsg:UINT, wParam:DWORD, lParam:DWORD
    cmp uMsg, WM_DESTROY;
    je _WM_DESTROY;
    cmp uMsg, WM_LBUTTONDOWN;
    je _WM_LBUTTONDOWN;

    invoke DefWindowProc, hWindow, uMsg, wParam, lParam;
    jmp _EndWndProc;

    _WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    invoke MessageBoxA, hWindow, offset MsgBoxTxt, offset WndTitleName, MB_OK or MB_ICONINFORMATION
    jmp _EndWndProc;

    _WM_DESTROY:
    invoke PostQuitMessage, 0h;

    _EndWndProc:

    Ret
WndProc EndP
end Entry;
```

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou bastante.

Comment: @Leonardo Disponha. Bem vindo ao SOpt. =)